# Difference between unsigned int and int

Tags: c, binary

I read about twos complement on wikipedia and on stack overflow, this is what I understood but I'm not sure if it's correct

**signed int**
the left most bit is interpreted as -2<sup>31</sup> and this how we can have negative numbers

**unsigned int**
the left most bit is interpreted as +2<sup>31</sup> and this is how we achieve large positive numbers

## update

What will the compiler see when we store 3 vs -3?

I thought 3 is always 00000000000000000000000000000011

and -3 is always 11111111111111111111111111111101

example for 3 vs -3 in C:

```
unsigned int x = -3;
int y = 3;

printf("%d %d\n", x, y); //  -3 3
printf("%u %u\n", x, y); // 4294967293 3
printf("%x %x\n", x, y); // fffffffd 3
```

Comment: `signed int` is interpreted as follows: flip all the bits, add 1 to this intermediate result, consider the final result as negative. For example: `0xFFFFFFFE --> 0x00000001 --> 0x00000002` hence `0xFFFFFFFE` is interpreted as `-2`.

Comment: @barakmanos I thought numbers are stored in twos complement whether negative or positive for example -3 is stored as  11111111111111111111111111111101 and +3 is stored as 
00000000000000000000000000000011

Comment: There is no difference in the way the values are stored. The only difference is in the way that the compiler interprets them, and compiles operations on them into assembly code. For example, the compiler may generate different assembly code for `x*y` when these variables are `signed` and when these variables are `unsigned`.

Comment: Try playing around with an online cacluator, like this one: http://www.free-test-online.com/binary/fractions_binary.html

Comment: @barakmanos : That is a *technique* for *human* interpretation.  The interpretation in the question remains correct.  If you add the place-values of all the non-zero bits taking the MSB place value as -2<sup>31<sup>, you end up with the same result.

Comment: What will the compiler see for 3 vs -3? you're saying both are 011 and the compiler will interpret them differently? I find it confusing

Comment: No, the compiler will consider `3` as `0x00000003` and `-3` as `0xFFFFFFFD`. But if you have some `unsigned int x` and somewhere else you have `signed int y = (signed int)x`, then the value of `x` is copied **as is** into `y`. And even though the values of `x` and `y` are seemingly identical, the compiler refers to operations applied on each of these variables in a different way.

Comment: Tip: use `"%X"` for printing, it will allow you to observe the values in hexadecimal format, which you can easily (using pen & paper) convert to binary format.

Comment: All what you are saying here is only true for two's complement representation of signed numbers. This is the most common one, but C still allows *ones complement* and *sign and magnitude* representation.

Answer (score 2):

Two's complement is a way to represent negative integers in binary.

First of all, here's a standard 32-bit integer ranges:

```
Signed = -(2 ^ 31) to ((2 ^ 31) - 1)
Unsigned = 0 to ((2 ^ 32) - 1)
```

In two's complement, a negative is represented by inverting the bits of its positive equivalent and adding 1:

```
10 which is 00001010 becomes -10 which is 11110110 (if the numbers were 8-bit integers).
```

Also, the binary representation is only important if you plan on using bitwise operators.
If your doing basic arithmetic, then this is unimportant.

The only time this may give unexpected results outside of the aforementioned times is getting the absolute value of the signed version of -(2 << 31) which will always give a negative.

Your problem does not have to do with the representation, but the type.
A negative number in an unsigned integer is represented the same, the difference is that it becomes a super high number since it must be positive and the sign bit works as normal.

You should also realize that ((2^32) - 5) is the exact same thing as -5 if the value is unsigned, etc.

Therefore, the following holds true:

```
unsigned int x = (2 << 31) - 5;
unsigned int y = -5;
if (x == y) {
  printf("Negative values wrap around in unsigned integers on underflow.");
}
else {
  printf( "Unsigned integer underflow is undefined!" );
}
```

Comment: @nevermind - Again, it only matters what the compiler see if your working directly on each individual bit; simle calculations do not care about the representation of the bits; thats the magic behind computers.

Comment: And yes, that is what the compiler sees if the underlying system uses two-s complement.

Comment: Can you tell me why this is important/needed? I don't think any of us really understand the question your asking.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers don't change, just the interpretation of the numbers. For most two's complement processors, add and subtract do the same math, but set a carry / borrow status assuming the numbers are unsigned, and an overflow status assuming the number are signed. For multiply and divide, the result may be different between signed and unsigned numbers (if one or both numbers are negative), so there are separate signed and unsigned versions of multiply and divide.

Comment: What do you mean by the numbers don't change? I thought in binary -3 is 11111111111111111111111111111101 and 3 is 
00000000000000000000000000000011

Comment: @nevermind - What I mean is 11111111111111111111111111111101 (hex FFFFFFFD) is +4294967293 if interpreted as an unsigned number or is -3 if interpreted as a signed number. If hex FFFFFFFD is added to FFFFFFFD, you get hex FFFFFFFA, with the carry bit set and the overflow bit not set.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct, allow me to explain a bit further for clarification purposes.

The difference between int and unsigned int is how the bits are interpreted. The machine processes unsigned and signed bits the same way, but there are extra bits added for signing. Two's complement notation is very readable when dealing with related subjects.

Example:

```
The number 5's, 0101, inverse is 1011.
```

In C++, it's depends when you should use each data type. You should use unsigned values when functions or operators return those values. ALUs handle signed and unsigned variables very similarly.

The exact rules for writing in Two's complement is as follows:

- If the number is positive, count up to 2^(32-1) -1
- If it is 0, use all zeroes
- For negatives, flip and switch all the 1's and 0's.

Example 2(The beauty of Two's complement):

```
-2 + 2 = 0 is displayed as 0010 + 1110; and that is 10000. With overflow at the end, we have our result as 0000;
```

Comment: "Best practice", really? I find *best practice* is to use the most natural type for what you are using it. For example, even though array indexing should be done using unsigned integers only, you may want to return "-1" as an error code somewhere you *also* return array indexes.

Comment: @Jongware did I not say most of the time? And I gave an exception as well, I even just bolded it.

Comment: Well, I still disagree. **Most** of the time it's best to use the best possible representation *for the data you are processing*. It totally depends on that data and what you are doing with it.

Comment: Why only partially correct?  I would say that it is exactly correct.  While affirmation of the OPs statement is the correct answer, the stuff about best practice is irrelevant and subjective and best deleted IMO.

Comment: @Jongware "Most of the time it's best to use the best possible representation *for the data you are processing*" If in the most likely case, the data processed can be represented as an int just fine, then most of the time int would be fine. I assert that the most likely case is when one represents data as an int.

Comment: @Jongware Ok, I have misconstrued what you said. I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

For 32-bit integers, for both signed and unsigned numbers, *n*-th bit is *always* interpreted as +2<sup>n</sup>.

For signed numbers with the 31th bit set, the result is adjusted by -2<sup>32</sup>.

Example: 
`1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`<sub>2</sub> as unsigned int is interpreted as 2<sup>31</sup>+2<sup>30</sup>+...+2<sup>1</sup>+2<sup>0</sup>. The interpretation of this as a signed int would be the same MINUS 2<sup>32</sup>, i.e. 2<sup>31</sup>+2<sup>30</sup>+...+2<sup>1</sup>+2<sup>0</sup>**-2<sup>32</sup>** = `-1`.

(Well, it can be said that for signed numbers with the 31th bit set, this bit is interpreted as -2<sup>31</sup> instead of +2<sup>31</sup>, like you said in the question. I find this  way a little less clear.)

Your representation of 3 and -3 is correct: 3 = `0x00000003`, -3 + 2<sup>32</sup> = `0xFFFFFFFD`.